Uncaught TypeError: number 0 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) -> Material UI Error
I'm trying to use MUI(Material UI) App bar. This one. Version : v6.1.1
In the sandbox, when I'm testing its working fine.
Though, when I'm using it in my project. It breaks with the following error :
Uncaught TypeError: number 0 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
Code :
export default function NavBar() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null); // error points to this line
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);


Check the complete code here
Detailed error message :
navBar.jsx:59 Uncaught TypeError: number 0 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at NavBar (navBar.jsx:59:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27490:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26505:1)

To know more about the error from MDN, refer.
Could anyone from the community assist me for this.

What's the chance you can reproduce the issue using a codesandbox so we could help you debugging? There is probably a difference between the sandbox and your code so we need to see it. Thanks

Hi @MoshFeu I just copied the code from here (official MUI sandbox) pasted in my project. Installed the required deps. And tried to run it. Thats how I encountered this error.
I`m using MUI from a long time. Copy pasting the code as it is always worked for me.
Though this time it didnt.

Sorry. Something is clearly different and without having the ability to play with the code and debug it, I'm unlikely to help :\ By the way, beside the error message, what exactly not working?

If you could just make a react project ,copy paste it in your newly made project. In that way you can test it. Bcz of the error I shared, the whole app bar is not showing up.
I had to comment away the import in app.jsx to eradicate rendering of it.

Hi @MoshFeu, I raised this as an issue in MUI github. One of the MUI team member already got assigned to me for the same.
I made a sample project for it GtiHub.
You can check it out if you would like to.

mmm works for me without errors: https://i.sstatic.net/pLUJkxfg.png

The MUI version I was using is 6.1.1.
I raised an issue regarding it on MUI github here
Also provided an sample project to showcase the error, refer this repo

Later in the MUI github issue that I raised,  they answered that I'm using tsx code in the jsx file.
Though in the 6.1.1 version, I already tried to change the tsx code to the jsx code but it didn't work.
Now, I just updated the version from 6.1.1 to 6.1.2 & it working fine.

Working solution : github repo

Conclusion : As per the MUI official's "I`m using tsx code in the jsx file", this was causing the error. Though, for me updating the version worked.
